# Change Background Color of Newly Added Rows in a tableview if a condition occurs?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a chat application in which I am adding the cells from an `NSMutableArray`. I am using pusher api. Now when the user removed from the channel I put an `NSNotifications`, and in that I am changing the value of a boolean, according to its value I am changing the background image of cell. in my `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` methode:

```
if([userid isEqualToString:uidstr])
    {
      if(offline==YES)
        {
         UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chat_cellreply02.png"]];
            [cell setBackgroundView:img];
            [img release]; 
          }
        else
        {
       UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chat_cellreply.png"]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:img];
        [img release]; 
        }
    }
```

It's  working, but here the problem is the background of all the cells are changing. I need to change the background of newly added cells only. Can anybody guide me in how to achieve this?

Comment: where have you written this method? cell for row index>?

Comment: then i guess the problem is not with this code but in setting the offline flag. I guess the flag is set as the same for all the cell.

Comment: check this by keeping a breakpoint there

Comment: how to make it applicable for only newly adding rows?

Comment: Show the complete code that you are usiong to populate cell, i.e. complete `cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod`

Comment: Does your `offline` variable belong to the user?

Comment: @ilmiacs no..when the user removed i am making this as yes,if the removed user is the selected user

Comment: What do you mean by newly added cells?

Comment: @Inoka the one which is coming after the user is offline.that means the latest cell

Comment: In that case you have to check with the index path row. In the current code if user is offline, it's obvious to change all the cells background.I hope your reloading table after adding a new message.

Comment: if u dnt mind can u tell me how to compare the indexpath row to find the new cell@Inoka

Comment: When you are putting the NSNotification, can't you get the number of items in the array and keep it separately for compare?

Comment: @Inoka i am talking about the message displaying cells,i guess u r thinking about users list.when he was typng the messages the other user becomes offline then in the new message only u will have to show the offline message

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24706/discussion-between-inoka-and-hacker)

Answer (score 1):

Make your `offline` variable belong to the structure you hold in your mutable array. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check for that variable.

Comment: that window is full of chat with that user only.so every cell gets updated.

Comment: so its the messages (not users) that your cells are displaying?

Comment: well, whatever you are displaying in a cell, you should make `offline`  belong to the individual cell.

Answer (score 0):

just check the last row of your table view and add the offline design there like

```
NSInteger sectionsAmount = [tableView numberOfSections];
    NSInteger rowsAmount = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
    if ([indexPath section] == sectionsAmount - 1 && [indexPath row] == rowsAmount - 1) {
        // This is the last row  here do your process
       }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a clean solution to your problem. It would affect only the last cell. So what if there is more than one cell after removal from channel? What if reconnect occurs?

Comment: if reconnect occurs i am using another notification to reload the tableview

Comment: so wat....it will affect the last added cell always .keeping the effected cell like that also